# Error when add maven lib to use rabbit queue

Tags: java, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

My project built in spring-boot swagger-ui and started ok.
But now, i want to add new app used Rabbit MQ in project. And I add maven lib in pom.xml.
Source hasn't error, but when start, it raise error.
So, how can i fix it?

```
 Application run failed
    
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.config.internalRabbitListenerAnnotationProcessor': Lookup method resolution failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.RabbitListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor] from ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2]

    Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.RabbitListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor] from ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2]
```

This is my pom.xml

```
<properties>
            <java.version>1.8</java.version>
            <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.1.1</maven-jar-plugin.version>
        </properties>
        <dependencies>
            
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            ....
    <dependency>
                <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
                <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
                <version>2.9.2</version>
                <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
                <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
                <version>2.9.2</version>
                <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-rabbit</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.10</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
```

Comment: Run with DEBUG logging enabled to get a full stack trace, and edit the question to add the stack trace. BTW, 2.3.x is no longer supported as OSS: https://spring.io/projects/spring-amqp#support

Comment: I used jdk1.8 and it only fit with version 2.3.x for version 52.  3.x is version 61.

Comment: 2.4.x works with Java 8.